# How to get a private key and address from mnemonic on cosmos in golang?

Tags: go, private-key, wallet, cosmos-sdk, cosm

I am trying to send coins on the cosmos-sdk blockchain. I succeeded in transferring coins using cosmjs. The code is as follows:

```js
import { Secp256k1HdWallet } from "@cosmjs/amino";
import { StargateClient, SigningStargateClient } from "@cosmjs/stargate";

(async () => {
    const toAddress = "your recipient address here";
    const rpcEndpoint = "your rpc endpoint here";
    const mnemonic = "your mnemonic here";
    const wallet = await Secp256k1HdWallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic, { prefix: "cosmos" });
    console.log(wallet);
    const [{ address, pubkey }] = await wallet.getAccounts();
    console.log(address);
    const client = await StargateClient.connect(rpcEndpoint);
    console.log("chain id: ", await client.getChainId());
    const balance = await client.getAllBalances(address);
    console.log("balance: ", balance);

    const signingClient = await SigningStargateClient.connectWithSigner(rpcEndpoint, wallet);

    console.log("sender balance before: ", await client.getAllBalances(address));
    console.log("receipient balance before: ", await client.getAllBalances(toAddress));

    const result = await signingClient.sendTokens(address, toAddress, [{ denom: "denom", amount: "800" }], {
        amount: [{ denom: "denom", amount: "20" }],
        gas: "200000",
    });

    console.log("result: ", result);

    console.log("sender balance after: ", await client.getAllBalances(address));
    console.log("receipient balance after: ", await client.getAllBalances(toAddress));
})();
```

I want to write a new program using golang that performs the same logic as this code. What should I do? I found something [similar content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70981681/how-to-generate-hd-wallet-keys-addresses-given-seed-phrase-with-cosmos-sdk), but it's result is not fitted on me.

I want three things. First, I want the same result as when I use "gaiad keys export  --unarmored-hex --unsafe" using gaiad. Second, I want to implement the same logic as with cosmjs in golang. Finally, I want a golang example that uses a locally stored key in the most efficient way possible.